# CS50, Plurality question, gives the wrong result

Tags: c, arrays, max, cs50, counting

Here is the plurality problem from CS50
I can't find fix the problem, please help

P.S I have another problem now, if there are 2 voters,1 is Alice,2nd is Bob
the program should print out both as winners, but it gives out first candidate as a winner,how to deal with it?

//Update vote totals given a new vote

```
bool vote(string name){
  for(int i=0;i<candidate_count; i++){
    if(strcmp(candidates[i].name,name)==0){
      candidates[i].vote++;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

//Print the winner (ot winners)of the election

```
void print_winner(void){
  int MaxVote=0;
  string Winner;
  for(int i=0;i<candidate_count; i++){
    if(candidates[i].vote>MaxVote){
      MaxVote=candidates[i].vote;
      Winner=candidates[i].name;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<candidate_count; i++){
    if(candidates[i].vote==MaxVote){
      printf("%s\n",Winner);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output

```
   ~/pset3/plurality/ $ ./plurality Alice Bob
Number of voters: 2
Vote: Alice
Vote: Bob
Alice
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your code, together with a description of the problems you have with it (what is is supposed to do, what really happens, what is the expected output for some specific input?)

Comment: @hanie Regarding `string`, the `cs50.h` header file defines it as an alias for `char *`, and it's likely that header file is used considering the `cs50` tag.

Comment: If you have a new problem please create a new question and undo your last edit. Consider making an answer to  bring this question to a clean end.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished this problem and what you need to do is print the first winner in your first "for" loop (in line 8 of your example) so it will print the first winner, then go back and print anyone who tied with them.